# Declare Parameters in Teradata query OR If-then-else

Tags: if-statement, parameters, teradata

I am new to Teradata. Here is the situation:

*If Current_date is < 15 of month then ?Startdate parameter = 1st of prev month and ?EndDate param = last date of current month*

```
SELECT ... FROM ViewA
WHERE date BETWEEN ?Startdate AND ?EndDate
```

*ELSE if Current_date >= 15 then Startdate parameter = 1st of Current month and EndDate param = last date of current month*

```
SELECT ... FROM ViewA
WHERE date BETWEEN ?Startdate AND ?EndDate
```

I was able to calculate dates in each case, but can't figure out:

**#1) how to put them in parameters. If I can put them in params then all I have to do is**

```
SELECT ... FROM ViewA
WHERE date BETWEEN ?Startdate AND ?EndDate
```

OR
 **#2) Write a IF-THEN-ELSE**

```
If Current_date is < 15 of month

    SELECT ... FROM ViewA
        WHERE Date BETWEEN 
        ADD_MONTHS((DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE)+1), -1) AND ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(DATE),0)
    ELSE
    SELECT ... FROM ViewA
        WHERE date BETWEEN 
        ADD_MONTHS((DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE)+1), 0)  AND ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(DATE),0) )

END IF
```

Please guide how to achieve #1 or #2. I CANNOT create function or stored procedure in teradata

Comment: Is your column really named 'date'?  If so, you have to put it in double-quotes. Not sure if it would work that way, or comparing with the actual date.

Comment: No, it is not named 'date' but it is a date field

Answer (score 0):

#2 using calendar as an example.

```
SELECT calendar_date from Sys_Calendar.CALENDAR
    WHERE calendar_date
       BETWEEN
         case when extract (day from current_date) < 15
                 then ADD_MONTHS((current_date - EXTRACT(DAY FROM current_date)+1), -1)
                 else             current_date - EXTRACT(DAY FROM current_date)+1
         end
       AND ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(current_date),0)
    order by calendar_date
    ;
```

I prefer the `current_date`, can't be confused with the datatype.

Comment: If we are talking about performance, it may be of benefit to put the above select into a volatile table and join it to your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE date 
BETWEEN Trunc(current_date - 14 , 'mon') -- first day of the month 14 days before today 
    AND last_day(current_date)           -- last day of current month
```